# Spring Data Multiple tables Generic repository

Tags: spring, rest, generics, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My application has an unknown number of tables that conform to one of two structures. Standard and Outsized. Unfortunately, it's not until runtime that I know how many tables are in the schema that corresponds to standard or outsized?

I've created generic Standard and Outsized repositories like so

```
public interface StandardTableRepository<T extends AbstractStandardTable>
    extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {}
```

but because the schema isn't static I can't create the Entities until runtime?

I understand JPA doesn't really cater for non-static schemas but is there any way that I could expose a generic restful service that would allow me to instantiate this repository at runtime perhaps using a table name supplied in the QueryParams?